# How does Postman handle image/png files?

Tags: postman

I created a postman request that works.

[image]

When I looked at this in fiddler I thought it looked weird.

[image]

Is that some sort of weird format? I expected that to be the binary string but instead it looks like that. What am I missing?

Ultimately I want to recreate this call in c# but would like to know how fiddler is picking up the contents like it is. It's almost like it's the raw png file.

Comment: "I expected that to be the binary string" – What do you expect a representation of binary data to look like when rendered as a string?

Comment: @Quentin unless I'm wrong (wouldn't be the first time) a string of letters and numbers that I could actually read.

Comment: So base64 or similar. Why do you expect that?

Comment: @Quentin I don't understand where you are trying to guide me here.  I don't know what else to expect if not that.  I'm just trying to learn what happens between selecting the file in postman and when fiddler captures the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you didn't encode the image like Base64. When we send an image through  REST apis, There are mainly 2 ways.

1. Encode the image - We can encode the image to Base64 and that encoded image can be send to Backend. [click here](https://www.base64-image.de/)
2. Upload the image and get the URL - this is the widly used method. We can upoad the image to cloud storage like AWS S3 and that will return a image URL. That URL can send to the backend.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the answer to the question I was trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

An image can put from `form-data` tab in `Body` of Postman.

[image]

[image]

This is same code by curl

```
curl https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer <your API-KEY>' \
    -F image='@bike.png' \
    -F n=2 \
    -F size="512x512"
```

This is same code by node.js with axios

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const FormData = require('form-data');
const fs = require('fs');

async function modifyImage() {
    //creates a Player in the database
    try {
        const form = new FormData();
        form.append('image', fs.readFileSync('bike.png'), 'bike.png');
        form.append('n', '2');
        form.append('size', '512x512');
        const response = await axios.post(
            'https://api.openai.com/v1/images/variations',
            form,
            {
                headers: {
                    ...form.getHeaders(),
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer <your API-KEY>>'
                }
            }
        )
        return Promise.resolve(response.data)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Errored trying to create a Image.', error)
        return Promise.reject(JSON.stringify({ success: 'error', body: 'Error Has Occured. An Admin has been contacted.' }))
    }
}
modifyImage()
    .then((result) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 4))
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: I was not asking how to do this. I successfully did this.

Comment: OK, I missed understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the fiddler is how binary data look like when the fiddler tries to render it as a string. Many bytes cannot be displayed as there are no matching text characters for them.

I saw in the comments you were expecting to see something like `0xA5CD78...`, which is base64 format - e.g. binary data converted to a string, typically used when there is a human in the middle (but not limited to) when each byte is converted to string/number format, you can read more details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).
While you certainly can use something like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tobase64string?view=net-8.0) in C# to convert data to base64 format, my guess would be that the server expects raw data rather than base64.